# How to avoid the "+" sign being included in serialize using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, sinatra

Well, I am very new to sinatra or RoR and I am constructing a table with some languages for translation purposes.

I save the data in the following form `(language => key => translation)`

When sending the data (translation) introduced by the user it is saved with a `+` in the middle. For example

```
en=>slogan=>we+save+energy
```

**Question:** How can I avoid this `+`?

Form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" >
    <table >
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>keys</th>
            <th>German</th>
            <th>English</th>
            <th>French</th>
            <
        </tr>

        <% @DE["de"].each do |key,value| %>     
         <tr>
            <td><%= i+= 1 %></td>
            <td id= "key<%= i %>"><%= key %></td>
            <td><textarea id="de<%= i %>" readonly ><%= value %></textarea></td>                        
            <td><textarea id="en<%= i %>" name="en<%= i %>"><%= @valuesEN[i] %></textarea></td>
            <td><textarea id="fr<%= i %>" name="fr<%= i %>"><%= @valuesFR[i] %></textarea></td>         

         </tr>
         <% end %>          
    </table>     
</form>
```

Here is the JQuery part:

```
$('textarea').change(function(e){
            var pointer = $(this);

            var color = pointer.css("background-color");
            if (color == 'rgb(250, 187, 0)'){
                var id = pointer.attr("id");
                var getNumberFromId = id.substr(2,3);
                var getLanguage = id.substr(0,2);
                var getKey = $("#key"+getNumberFromId).html();

                e.stopPropagation();
                pointer.css('background-color','#8Fbc8F'); // Change field to green
                toServer(pointer,getKey, getLanguage);              
            }           
          });

function toServer(pointer, key, language) {         
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'translator/translate/'+language+'/'+key,
                    data: {"data":pointer.serialize()},                 
                    success: function(data){

                    }
                }); 
          }
```

Receiving the data in the server:

```
post '/translator/:lang/:key' do

  language = params[:lang]
  key = params[:key]
  translation = params[:data]

  File.open('translation_file.txt', 'a') do |f|
     f.print language
     f.print "=>" 
     f.print key
     f.print "=>" 
     f.puts translation

   end  

end
```

Comment: I found a solution. Not matter what, serialize does what he wants. So instead of using it I use serializeArray(), which sends the data correctly to the server. Example: we save the moon instead of we+save+the+moon